# How to catch a specific SqlException error?

Tags: c#, exception, sqlexception

**Q:** Is there a better way to handle SqlExceptions?

The below examples rely on interpreting the text in the message.

**Eg1:** I have an existing try catch to handle if a table does not exist.
*Ignore the fact that I could check if the table exists in the first place.*

```
try
{
    //code
}
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{
        if (sqlEx.Message.StartsWith("Invalid object name"))
        {
            //code
        }
        else
            throw;
}
```

**Eg2:** without the try catch showing duplicate key exception

```
if (sqlEx.Message.StartsWith("Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"))
```

**Solution: The start of my SqlExceptionHelper**

```
//-- to see list of error messages: select * from sys.messages where language_id = 1033 order by message_id
public static class SqlExceptionHelper
{
    //-- rule: Add error messages in numeric order and prefix the number above the method

    //-- 208: Invalid object name '%.*ls'.
    public static bool IsInvalidObjectName(SqlException sex)
    { return (sex.Number == 208); }

    //-- 2601: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.
    public static bool IsDuplicateKey(SqlException sex)
    { return (sex.Number == 2601); }
}
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The SqlException has a [Number property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) that you can check.  For duplicate error the number is 2601.

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   switch (e.Number)
   {
      case 2601:
         // Do something.
         break;
      default:
         throw;
   }
 }
```

To get a list of all SQL errors from you server, try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM sysmessages
```

**Update**

This can now be simplified in C# 6.0

```
catch (SqlException e) when (e.Number == 2601)
{
   // Do something.
}
```

Comment: And you can filter by the language: select * from sysmessages where msglangid=1033. That is for English

Comment: Hi @Richard Schneider I know this answer has aged, but I was wondering are there new (better) solutions to also create the message automated, since I use MVC, and every model property has its own "translation" I would assume that I could write a standard message with the property name (because I map everytime they are exactly the same) and than get the renamed property name to show the message like "There is already a record known with [Value] as [FieldName] in our system, please choose differently".

Comment: Would an `catch (Exception e)` catch an SQL exception? Or is it mandatory to use `catch (SqlException e)`? Because somehow  `catch (Exception e)` does't catch "SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row".

Comment: @JedatKinports we would need to see your code, but a general exception will catch an SQL exception as the later inherits from the former. For example there's no number, server, state or client connection id properties on a general exception. If you want the specific details available from an SqlException you need to explicitly catch it. Generally you chain multiple catches together, starting with the most specific and ending with a general Exception catch

Comment: Kudos for the C# 6.0 tip

Comment: Please note that `SqlException.Number` might be `0` on Linux. https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1773

Answer (score 20):

Sort of, kind of. See [Cause and Resolution of Database Engine Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms365262.aspx)

```
class SqllErrorNumbers
{ 
   public const int BadObject = 208;
   public const int DupKey = 2627;
}

try
{
   ...
}
catch(SqlException sex)
{
   foreach(SqlErrorCode err in sex.Errors)
   {
      switch (err.Number)
      {
      case SqlErrorNumber.BadObject:...
      case SqllErrorNumbers.DupKey: ...
      }
   }
}
```

The problem though is that a good DAL layer would us `TRY/CATCH` *inside* the T-SQL (stored procedures), with a pattern like [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/). Alas a T-SQL `TRY/CATCH` block cannot raise the original error code, will have to raise a *new* error, with code above 50000. This makes client side handling a problem. In the next version of SQL Server there is a new [THROW](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/22/sql-server-v-next-denali-exploring-throw) construct that allow to re-raise the original exception from T-SQL catch blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and links. btw: I like catching sex :) I will start using that instead of sqlEx for fun. Reminds me of the old classic asp days `On Error Goto Hell`

Comment: This just doesn't sound right, err in sex.Errors ;)

Comment: Inside wont' handle timeout and transport exceptions, so even with perfect handling with a sproc, it is still appropriate for call to handle.

Answer (score 9):

It is better to use error codes, you don't have to parse.

```
try
{
}
catch (SqlException exception)
{
    if (exception.Number == 208)
    {

    }
    else
        throw;
}
```

How to find out that 208 should be used:

```
select message_id
from sys.messages
where text like 'Invalid object name%'
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will create a SqlException helper. Also, thank you very much for pointing me to the sql table of errors.  select * from sys.messages where language_id = 1033

Comment: select * from master.dbo.sysmessages where msglangid=1033
or
SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033

to filter only english messages.

Besides, the message_id in system table is not a one-one map as SqlException.Number.  I've verified on C# and SQL Server 2008 R2, for Timeout error, the SqlException.Number is -2,  but there's no such an error definition in system tables.

Comment: How get language_id  ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want list of error messages met in Sql server, you can see with

```
SELECT *
FROM master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Answer (score 2):

You can evaluate **based** on severity type. 
Note to use this you must be subscribed to OnInfoMessage

```
conn.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage;
conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
```

Then your OnInfoMessage would contain:

```
foreach(SqlError err in e.Errors) {
//Informational Errors
if (Between(Convert.ToInt16(err.Class), 0, 10, true)) {
    logger.Info(err.Message);
//Errors users can correct.
} else if (Between(Convert.ToInt16(err.Class), 11, 16, true)) {
    logger.Error(err.Message);
//Errors SysAdmin can correct.
} else if (Between(Convert.ToInt16(err.Class), 17, 19, true)) {
    logger.Error(err.Message);
//Fatal Errors 20+
} else {
    logger.Fatal(err.Message);
}}
```

This way you can evaluate on severity rather than on error number and be more effective. You can find more information on severity [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx).

```
private static bool Between( int num, int lower, int upper, bool inclusive = false )
{
    return inclusive
        ? lower <= num && num <= upper
        : lower < num && num < upper;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a better way to handle SQLException, there are a couple things you could do.  First, Spring.NET does something similar to what you are looking for (I think).  Here is a link to what they are doing:

http://springframework.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/dao.html

Also, instead of looking at the message, you could check the error code (`sqlEx.Number`).  That would seem to be a better way of identifying which error occurred.  The only problem is that the error number returned might be different for each database provider.  If you plan to switch providers, you will be back to handling it the way you are or creating an abstraction layer that translates this information for you.

Here is an example of a guy who used the error code and a config file to translate and localize user-friendly error messages:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130731181042/http://weblogs.asp.net/guys/archive/2005/05/20/408142.aspx

Comment: Used the archive.org link to fix the broken link.

Answer (score 1):

With MS SQL 2008, we can list supported error messages in the table sys.messages

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with code first, C# 7 and entity framework 6.0.0.0. it works for me

```
Add()
{
     bool isDuplicate = false;
     try
     {
       //add to database 
     }
     catch (DbUpdateException ex)
     {
       if (dbUpdateException.InnerException != null)
       {
          var sqlException = dbUpdateException.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;
          if(sqlException != null)
             isDuplicate = IsDuplicate(sqlException);
       } 
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
        isDuplicate = IsDuplicate(ex);
     }  
     if(isDuplicate){
       //handle here
     }
}

bool IsDuplicate(SqlException sqlException)
{
    switch (sqlException.Number)
    {
        case 2627:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

**N.B:** my query for add item to db is in another project(layer)

Comment: I am having issues finding a namespace that contains DbUpdateException .  I am using Entity Framework 5.0.0.0.  But when I try to declare a Exception type in the catch statement of  DbUpdateException  it shows me as missing an assembly or reference.  When I looked up the that exception type in MSDN it said it was part of the EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.

Comment: Never mind.  Found it in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.   But shouldn't the code read  if(sqlException != null)
             isDuplicate = IsDuplicate(sqlException);

Comment: @user1161391 I think it execute first catch (DbUpdateException ex). it same here

Comment: I like this answer as I'm doing `Code First` too. I want to say I agree with @user1161391. Inside the `catch (DbUpdateException ex)`, the line `if(sqlException == null) isDuplicate = IsDuplicate(sqlException);` will always send `null` to `IsDuplicate()`, or are we missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you rookies out there who may throw a SQL error when connecting to the DB from another machine(For example, at form load), you will find that when you first setup a datatable in C# which points to a SQL server database that it will setup a connection like this:

```
this.Table_nameTableAdapter.Fill(this.DatabaseNameDataSet.Table_name);
```

You may need to remove this line and replace it with something else like a traditional connection string as mentioned on MSDN, etc.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008