# How to handle SqlException

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I've got some SQL handling code in C#, which can throw a number of exceptions when handling UNION clauses. I would like to detect which particular exception is being thrown so as to handle it accordingly. When testing my application, these two errors are thrown:

[image]

[image]

How can I differentiate between each one and recognise which one was thrown? I cannot simply copy/paste the error message and place it in an `if-statement` as the field names and schema will not always be the same.

```
try
 {
   adapter.Fill(dtResults);
 }
 catch (SqlException ex)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SqlException you are catching has rich information on it such as the error number.  This allows you to handle the conditions individually:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx

Comment: @DotNET: You should have mentioned(or byranmac) that the number is just the wrapper around the **first** exception. You can loop `ex.Errors` as shown in the link above. That might be the reason why you got the same number on both errors.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `catch` statement you can use:

```
   if (ex.ToLower.Contains("conversion failed")
       MessageBox.Show("Error: a conversion failed");
   if (ex.ToLower.Contains("multi-part identifier")
       MessageBox.Show("this is the other error!");
```

Just one method of many to get around this issue :)

Comment: Not a good approach. Now your code unnecessarily relies on the language(maybe even on the db-version since the messages are not set in stone).

Comment: This was the only method I knew to catch specific errors. I was just providing an alternate way to achieving the same result - now I realise that there are better ways of doing it. Answering questions is a learning experience too.

Answer (score 1):

The SqlException has a Number property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) that you can check.

Take a look at this answer for details, it seems to be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222003/1758762