# Get SSRS report to show SQLexception

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, reporting-services, report

I have a problem where i want to show specific Exception Errors inside my reports(making life easier for the guy who has to fix things if they are borken).

I want my SQLexception

[Not allowed to embed images(SQL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7nqG.png)
[image]

and my SSRS exception

[Not allowed to embed images(SSRS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xj3m.png)
[image]

to both show the SQL exception message.

Does anybody have a clue how i can fix this?

so far I have only hit a wall

Comment: I think u want to use the SQLException Number Property as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221951/sqlexception-catch-and-handling

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to wrap the SQL in a `try ... catch` block ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)). This gives you control over what happens when the SQL throws an error and allows you to see the Error Message ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx)).

In order for you to be able to display the error in SSRS, you have to still return a `SELECT` statement with the same columns you would have normally. This is because SSRS needs to know the column names ahead of time. So add a column to your original dataset like so:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ... , NULL as ERROR_MESSAGE
```

And then add this in your `catch` block:

```
SELECT NULL AS Col1, NULL as Col2, ... , ERROR_MESSAGE() as ERROR_MESSAGE
```

Then, in the report, you can check the `Max(Fields!.ERROR_MESSAGE.Value)` to determine if you should display the error message in that column or regular data.