# C# Service Based Database not writing to DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, insert

I am trying to write an application in Visual Studio C# to write to a service based database. The issue I am having is that I am not getting any errors, however nothing is saving to the database after relaunching the application...

I know it is writing because it will not allow duplicate primary keys. It's almost as if it's a temporary database... If this is the case how do I make it a persistent service based database?

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        // Connection to DB
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MTR_Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        // Insert Query
        string insertquery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Job01 ([Item #], [Manufacturer], [Mill Location], [Product Description], [Weld Seam Type], [Outer Dimension], [Wall Thickness], [Coating], [Grade], [Heat], [ANSI/ASME], [Purchase Order], [Standard]) VALUES(@ItemNum, @Manufacturer, @MillLocation, @ProductDescription, @WeldSeamType, @OuterDimension, @WallThickness, @Coating, @Grade, @Heat, @ANSIASME, @PurchaseOrder, @Standard)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertquery, con);

        // open connection
        con.Open();

        // Parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNum", item__TextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", manufacturerTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MillLocation", mill_LocationTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDescription", product_DescriptionTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeldSeamType", weld_Seam_TypeTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OuterDimension", outer_DimensionTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WallThickness", wall_ThicknessTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coating", coatingTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", gradeTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heat", heatTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ANSIASME", aNSI_ASMETextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchaseOrder", purchase_OrderTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", standardTextBox.Text);

        // Execute
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // close connection
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // catch error
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I really can't put my finger on what is going on.

Comment: I guess more so, I want it to act as SQLite... Without an active server and within the application. Is this possible with SQL Express embedded in Visual Studio?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221951/sqlexception-catch-and-handling on exception handling with SQL-Server.  Also use a direct file path to the MDF and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MTR_Database`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MTR_Database;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: Will do @marc_s Thanks for the info... I will try this out. I've been working in MySql quite a bit, but trying to switch to SQL for work... it's been a horrible experience so far. Besides the fact, Again I will work on this. If it works I'll Upvote the answer :) I may finish it tomorrow since It's almost time to gett off work :(

Comment: You were exactly right... I was looking at the wrong DB file. Everything was inserting properly. I guess I have to learn how to make a new server and give it a database name. I can then just pretty much treat it like mySQL. I'll probably just run it off a server rather than local.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before and just solved it.

Don't use `|DataDirectory|\MTR_Database.mdf`, use the full path.