# How to catch and handle a duplicate error while inserting data through a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to insert data into a table.

This is how I call the stored procedure from the controller method:

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info] @call_id, @user_id, @call_arrive, @call_end, @info",
                    new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id),
                    new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id),
                    new SqlParameter("call_arrive", call_arrive),
                    new SqlParameter("call_end", call_end),
                    new SqlParameter("info", info)
                    ).ToList();

 var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(insert_query); // <-- using Newtonsoft.Json
 return Json(jsonResult);
```

If I insert a `call_id` value that is already stored in the table, I get this error, which is correct:

> Message": "An error has occurred
>
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Call_Inf__427DCE6904E3DF9B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Call_Info'. The duplicate key value is (91390).

Is there a way to catch this error in the controller?

Comment: Modify your stored procedure to *avoid* such errors completely. Add a WHERE clause in your INSERT statement for example, or replace INSERT into a MERGE that updates any existing records

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you! I will use this for an update stored-procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely.
You can use a `try catch` block to capture the `SqlException`

```
try
{
    //SQL query
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    foreach(SqlError err in ex.Errors)
    {
        if((err.Number == 2601) //unique nonclustered index
            || (err.Number == 2627)) //unique constraint
        //handle it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
catch(SqlException ex) 
{

}
```

[How to catch a specific SqlException error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221951/how-to-catch-a-specific-sqlexception-error)